# Every other image shows up in jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, keylistener, imageicon

I have altered my code from creating a new image icon each time I move my stickman, but now whenever I am facing left it skips the picture that makes it look like he is walking.

I can't figure out why, when I try to walk through the program step by step it seems like it should be alternating between stationary `stickman1left` and walking `stickman2left` but it only shows `stickman1left`.
[image: star][image: Stickman]

```
package my.testing1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Jamie
 */
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JLabel Stickman = new JLabel();//(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman.png"));
    JLabel cords = new JLabel();
    JLabel bg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\background.png"));
    JLabel star = new JLabel();//(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\star1.png"));
    ImageIcon Star1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\star1.png");
    ImageIcon Star2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\star2.png");
    ImageIcon StickmanRight = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman.png");
    ImageIcon Stickman2Right = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2.png");
    ImageIcon StickmanLeft = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickmanLeft.png");
    ImageIcon Stickman2Left = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stitckman2Left.png");

    int locx = 0;
    int locy = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x = Stickman.getX();
    int y = Stickman.getY();
    String cor = Integer.toString(x) + " " + Integer.toString(y);
    boolean ph;
    boolean left;
    boolean Sph;

    public GUI() {
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.cords.setText(cor);
        Stickman.setBounds(x, y, 120, 120);
        cords.setBounds(20, 170, 50, 50);
        bg.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        star.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);

        cor = Integer.toString(x) + " " + Integer.toString(y);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                    star.setIcon(Star1);
                    star.setLocation(x + 80, y + 30);
                }
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    if (y > 0 | y == 0) {
                        y = y + 10;
                    }
                    if (y > 440) {
                        y = y - 10;
                    }
                    Stickman.setLocation(x, y);
                    if (ph == false) {
                        if (left == true) {
                            Stickman.setIcon(Stickman2Left);
                        } else {
                            Stickman.setIcon(Stickman2Right);
                        }

                        ph = true;
                    } else {
                        if (left == true) {
                            Stickman.setIcon(StickmanLeft);

                        } else {
                            Stickman.setIcon(StickmanRight);
                        }
                        ph = false;
                    }
                    repaint();
                    cords.setLocation(20, 170);
                    cor = Integer.toString(x) + " " + Integer.toString(y);
                    cords.setText(cor);
                }
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    if (y > 440 | y > 0) {
                        y = y - 10;
                    }
                    if (y < 0) {
                        y = y + 10;
                    }
                    Stickman.setLocation(x, y);
                    if (ph == false) {
                        if (left == true) {
                            Stickman.setIcon(Stickman2Left);

                        } else {
                            Stickman.setIcon(Stickman2Right);
                        }
                        ph = true;
                    } else {
                        if (left == true) {
                            Stickman.setIcon(StickmanLeft);

                        } else {
                            Stickman.setIcon(StickmanRight);
                        }
                        ph = false;
                    }
                    repaint();
                    cords.setLocation(20, 170);
                    cor = Integer.toString(x) + " " + Integer.toString(y);
                    cords.setText(cor);
                }
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    if (x < 0) {
                        x = x + 10;
                    }
                    if (x > 0) {
                        x = x - 10;
                    }
                    Stickman.setLocation(x, y);
                    left = true;
                    if (ph == false) {
                        Stickman.setIcon(Stickman2Left);
                        ph = true;
                    } else {
                        Stickman.setIcon(StickmanLeft);
                        ph = false;
                    }
                    repaint();
                    cords.setLocation(20, 170);
                    cor = Integer.toString(x) + " " + Integer.toString(y);
                    cords.setText(cor);
                }

                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    if (x < 690) {
                        x = x + 10;
                    }
                    if (x > 690) {
                        x = x - 10;
                    }
                    Stickman.setLocation(x, y);
                    left = false;
                    if (ph == false) {
                        Stickman.setIcon(Stickman2Right);
                        ph = true;
                    } else {

                        Stickman.setIcon(StickmanRight);
                        ph = false;
                    }

                    repaint();
                    cords.setLocation(20, 170);
                    cor = Integer.toString(x) + " " + Integer.toString(y);
                    cords.setText(cor);
                }
            }
        });
        Stickman.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            //@Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    boolean dd = Stickman.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled();
                    boolean ff = Stickman.requestFocusInWindow();
                    repaint();
                }
            }

        });

        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.setSize(700, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(GUI.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.add(cords);
        p.setLayout(null);
        p.add(star);
        p.add(Stickman);
        p.add(bg);

        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(p);
        getContentPane().add(js);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 0));
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(10, 10, 700, 700));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 700));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 604, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GUI frame = new GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: **off-topic:** Use Java naming convention. Variables begin with lower case letters. At a quick glance it looks like your are calling method staticly, which is very confusing.

Comment: While a mess, you code works, in that, when I press left or right, it alternates between the two directional state images on each press...I'd be making sure that you images are correct and what you are expecting to be displayed...

Comment: weird, when I press left it shows the first pic (stickmanLeft) then if I press left again I see nothing, then again I see the same pic

Comment: @Peavey2787 If you're not seeing the second image, it's likey that the second image hasn't been loaded...

Comment: OMG I had the img name misspelled ImageIcon Stickman2Left = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stitckman2Left.png");

Comment: What could I do to make the code not so messy?

Comment: @Peavey2787 Start by using key bindings instead of key listeners, I explained how to [in a recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625093/java-swing-keylistener-2d-boulderdash/22638101#22638101). I also offered you to help with this in your previous question. You now have enough reputation to upload images.

Comment: I uploaded the images. Thanks for all the help

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.