# Using update and repaint in java

Tags: java, paint, program-entry-point, keylistener, repaint

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719228/how-do-i-call-keylistener-and-use-keyevent) regarding this same program before. I solved the issues I had then, and I now have rooted out a different problem.  When I run the code it shows a small blue box on the screen.  It is supposed to move when you press the arrow keys and I have discovered that if you click the character and hold an arrow key for a moment then it will move.  What I need is to make it refreshes the screen automatically, I believe I need an `update()` method for that, but I am not sure.  If anybody can help me figure this out or improve my code in some way that would be helpful.  I made some changes based off of some comments I received on my previous question.

CharacterTest.java:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Canvas;
//import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CharacterTest extends JFrame{

public CharacterTest() 
{
    super("Character Test");                                //instantiate a window to draw the character in
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    //this will stop the program when it closes

    setSize(800, 800);                  //create the window

    MCharacter C = new MCharacter();    //call the box so that it can be affected

    getContentPane().add(C);            //draws the character on the window

    setVisible(true);                   //show the window

    while(C.determine(C.getX(), C.getY()) == false)     //as long as the character is witin a particular area
    {
        if(C.getUpKey() == true)                //if the up arrow key is pressed
        {
            C.up();                             //set the y variable to a higher position
        }
        if(C.getDownKey() == true)              //if the down arrow key is pressed
        {
            C.down();                           //set the y variable to a lower positon
        }
        if(C.getRightKey() == true)             //if the right arrow key is pressed
        {
            C.right();                          //set the x variable ro a more right position
        }
        if(C.getLeftKey() == true)              //if the left key is pressed
        {
            C.left();                           //set the x variable to a more left position
        }
        repaint();                              //repaint the character at a new position
        try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex){
            }
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    CharacterTest test = new CharacterTest();   //calls the method which creates the screeen, the character, and checks for key srokes
}
}
```

MCharacter.java:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Canvas;
//import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MCharacter extends Canvas{

//these will be the instance variables for the character's parameters- its size and its location
private int width;
private int height;
private int x;
private int y;


//these will be turned true if the corresponding key is pressed - defined in the private class line 132
private boolean leftKey = false;
private boolean rightKey = false;
private boolean upKey = false;
private boolean downKey = false;


//some constructors that would easily be called
public MCharacter() 
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setWidth(10);
    setHeight(10);
    setX(400);
    setY(400);
    addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());        //adds a key listener as the private class below (line 152)
}

public MCharacter(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setWidth(10);
    setHeight(10);
    setX(xPos);
    setY(yPos);
    addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());        //adds a key listener as the private class below (line 152)
}

public MCharacter(int wth, int hgt, int xPos, int yPos)
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setWidth(wth);
    setHeight(hgt);
    setX(xPos);
    setY(yPos);
    addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());        //adds a key listener as the private class below (line 152)
}

//setters for each of the variables
public void setWidth(int wth)
{
    width = wth;
}

public void setHeight(int hgt)
{
    height = hgt;
}

public void setX(int xPos)
{
    x = xPos;
}

public void setY(int yPos)
{
    y = yPos;
}

//getters for each of the varaibles
public int getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

public int getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

//used to determine if the character should move
public void setUpKey(boolean setUp)
{
    upKey = setUp;
}
public void setDownKey(boolean setDown)
{
    downKey = setDown;
}
public void setRightKey(boolean setRight)
{
    rightKey = setRight;
}
public void setLeftKey(boolean setLeft)
{
    leftKey = setLeft;
}

public boolean getUpKey()
{
    if(upKey == true) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean getDownKey()
{
    if(downKey == true) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean getRightKey()
{
    if(rightKey == true) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean getLeftKey()
{
    if(leftKey == true) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//the following class is goign to be used to determine if an arrow key is being pressed
private class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        switch (e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:              //if left key is pressed
            setLeftKey(true);                       //set this boolean to true
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:             //if right key is pressed
            setRightKey(true);                  //set this boolean to true
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:                //if the up key is pressed
            setUpKey(true);                     //set this boolean to true
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:              //if the down key is pressed
            setDownKey(true);                       //set this boolean to true
            break;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        switch (e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:              //if left key is released
            setLeftKey(false);                  //set this boolean to false
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:             //if right key is released
            setRightKey(false);                 //set this boolean to false
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:                //if up key is released
            setUpKey(false);                        //set this boolean to false
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:              //if down key is released
            setDownKey(false);                  //set this boolean to false
            break;
        }
    }
}

//I am going to call the paint method here and create a small box that I will use as the character
public void paint(Graphics window)
{
    window.setColor(Color.BLUE);                //sets the color of the character
    window.fillRect(x, y, width, height);       //sets the dimensions of the character
}

//this method will be used to keep checking for a key pressed: while this is false check for a keytyped
public boolean determine(int x, int y)
{
    if( x >= 10 && x <= 790 && y >= 10 && y <= 790)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//the following methods will be to move the character
public void up()
{
    setY(getY()-2);
}
public void down()
{
    setY(getY()+2);
}
public void right()
{
    setX(getX()+2);
}
public void left()
{
    setX(getX()-2);
}
}
```

Comment: For one, **Don't** add the key listener from inside your `paint` method

Comment: well then where should I be adding it?

Comment: The constructor seems like a fitting place

Comment: Thanks, I'll move it there, but I doubt that will fix my main problem.

Comment: Just so you understand why that's such a huge problem: components can have more than one of the same listener. Each on gets added to a queue of listeners that each will call back when an event is fired. So every time `paint` is called (which can be for _any_ number of reasons), you are adding _another_ listener to the component. Imagine `paint` has been called 10 times. You then has 10 listeners registered with your component and 10 call backs. See the problem? `paint` should be strictly for painting.

Comment: Actually that makes some sense, I was working on it last night and if I ran the program for a while my memory would get overloaded, so thank you for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 0):

To do this smoothly, you will have to move the while-loop out of the `CharacterTest` constructor and execute this on a separate Thread. Also define your `leftKey`, `rightKey`, `upKey` and `downKey` fields as `volatile` to prevent synchronization issues between the AWT/Swing Event Thread and your rendering Thread (since the event thread and your rendering thread may be accessing these fields at the same time).

If you execute the Canvas' `repaint()` from your own separate Thread, you should also `setIgnoreRepaint(true)` in MCharacter's constructor to prevent Swing from repainting your Canvas as well.

Also, to make your code more readable, I suggest you define a method in `MCharacter` called `move()` and execute the contents of your while loop there (it makes sense to 'move' a character). the `run()` method with the loop will then look like this:

```
@Override public void run() {
    while (character.determine()) {
        character.move();
    }
}
```