# KeyListener active only after click on canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, focus, keylistener

I have a class which implements `KeyListener`, all's working fine, but there a little problem that my `KeyListener` works only after I click on a Canvas, so if I start a game, I have to click once on it and then I can use my keyboard, code:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    ....
    initGame() {
        ...
        addKeyListener(new Keyboard());
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    private class Keyboard implements KeyListener {
        ...
    }
}
```

-is there a method which make my canvas "active" after creating?

Comment: It is because it does not have focus.  For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  Also, rendering in Swing is typically done in a `JPanel` rather than a `Canvas`..

Comment: set the focus by calling `setFocusable(true);` on the component.

Comment: @Braj  No that method just sets a component **focusable**.  You are describing `requestFocusInWindow()`.

Comment: @Braj From the descripth problem (and sample code), the componet is already focusable, as the OP can click the componet and activate the key listener...

Comment: Got it. My mistake... I just read you first comment. :) I haven't seen OP code.

Comment: requestFocusInWindow() is not working..

Comment: The it sounds like you habnother ompoentng is stealing focus

Comment: You can bypass most of `KeyListener`'s problems if you use key bindings as @AndrewThompson suggested. For the hundredth time this week, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625093/java-swing-keylistener-2d-boulderdash/22638101#22638101) is a short answer I gave on creating key bindings.

Comment: Please validate whether `Canvas` is added before making `JFrame` visible or not?

Comment: I changed Canvas to JPanel, and now its working i used key bindings instead of KeyListener, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

`KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has focus.

While you can use `requestFocusInWindow`, there is no guarantee that focus will be transferred to the component and if focus is lost for some reason (you click on another component), then you back to square one.

A better solution is to use a `JComoponet` based componet (like `JPanel`) and make use of the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API which allows you to define the focus level that triggers the key events

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue if `Canvas` is added after making `JFrame` visible.

Call

```
frame.setVisible(true)
```

in the end after adding all the components on it.

This is what happening with me if I add `Canvas` after making `JFrame` visible and I have to click on `Canvas` to gain focus on it.

---

-- EDIT --

Sample code to understand it (try after un-commenting last `frame.setVisible(true)`)

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CanvasDemo extends Canvas implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    public CanvasDemo() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        CanvasDemo apple = new CanvasDemo();            
        frame.add(apple);

        frame.setTitle("The Game");
        // frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    // animates rectangle
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("action performed");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("key pressed");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("key released");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("key typed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the information provided if the component was added after the frame was made visible the OP wouldn't be able to click on the frame and see the key events, in order for this to happen, the canvas has to be displayable on the screen...

Comment: Add `setBackground(Color.RED);` into the constructor and you will note that the `Canvas` is visible when the frame makes it onto the screen.  The call to `setResizable` is probably invalidating the container. Oh and [intial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and `setSize` will have no effect as the frame is using it's own layout manager, so the settings will be discard when the container is called upon to be layed out.

Comment: I have tried it after removing `setResizable`. Now the frame is displayed without any height and width. I expand it and hit the key. but still its not working. Once I click on frame. key listeners start working.

Comment: Follow my first suggestion. Set the background color of the `Canvas` object.  Once you resize the frame, the frame invalidated and the `Canvas` is made displayable and will respond to events - that's my point.  From what the OP is saying, the time they call setVisible is not relevant to there problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the next way: I created Canvas object, added KeyListener to it and made this object focusable. After these operations I added Canvas object to JFrame and everything started working fine.