# Buttons in JFrame are active after creating new JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have `Menu` class with buttons - newGame and quit:

```
public class Menu extends JFrame
{
  JButton newGameButton = new JButton();
  ...

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    game.start();
  }
}
```

After clicking on the button, new game starts, so this class :

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  private Thread t;

  public void start()
  {
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();

    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

After I create the `JPanel`, game starts and buttons aren't visible, but if I click on the position of a button the button blinks and proceed. I'm painting with `paintComponent(g)` method, I was painting on `Canvas` instead of `JPanel` before and it was OK, after I changed it to `JPanel` I have this problem, any ideas?

EDIT: [here](http://pastie.org/8978453) are the working (Canvas) and not-working(JPanel) codes, in JPanel i can click the button as many times as i want.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  As an aside, that `Runnable` looks wrong.  All GUI updates should be on the EDT, and the `Thread` that runs that, is not it.

Comment: Have you tried my solution posted at [KeyListener active only after click on canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724286/keylistener-active-only-after-click-on-canvas/22724561#22724561). As per your comments it was working fine in Canvas but now its not working after using JPanel. Try my solution, you don't need to convert it into JPanel.

Comment: Thanks for help Braj, but i removed KeyListener, now I'm using key bindings and its working perfect.

Comment: i edited my question and added codes

Comment: *"..added codes"* 2 x code snippets `!=` 1 x MCVE.  Post an **MCVE**.  Voting to close for lack of one.  And a tip: Add @Braj (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood corectly, your JPanel spawns on top of the game menu buttons and you can still click them?

Make your menu inside a panel and make it invisible when game starts

ex:

```
game.start();
gameMenu.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: If i do this then i can' see both - JFrame and JPanel

Comment: Well isn't the JPanel inside JFrame? then make the JFrame invisible

Comment: JPanel is inside JFrame